# How to reverse a unicode string using AutoHotKey and paste it?

Tags: scripting, autohotkey

I have this reverse function which works in english,

However it doesn't work with hebrew,

```
Reverse(string)
{
length := StrLen(string)
Loop, parse, string
{
loc := Abs(A_Index - length) + 1
revloc%loc% := A_LoopField
}
Loop %length%
final .= revloc%A_index%
return final
}
ReverseByAddress(address,len){
   Loop % (len){
      out.=Chr(NumGet(address+0,len-A_index,"Char"))
   }
   Return out
}

^m::
;ClipSaved := ClipboardAll 
;text.="new line of some text`n"
text= %Clipboard%
clipboard := Reverse(text)
send, ^v
```

Any help with making this work with Unicode will be appreciated.

Comment: I forgot the mention that the function takes "hello" and returns "olleh"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been solved without saving the data back to the clipboard:

```
^,::
text= %Clipboard%
newText := Reverse(text)
send, %newText%
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you get this kind of schedule, at 2 or 3 characters?

```
2 character ex.  -AutoHotKey -> uAotoHKtYe 
................................uA ot oH Kt Ye
```

or

```
3 character ex.  -AutoHotKey -> tuAoHoeKty 
                          ......tuA oHo eKt y
```